# Avoid changing of td bgcolor on some condition using jquery?

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, background-color

Hi,

I have a table of 16 td tags.Every td has mouser over and out events which changes background color of td's. But the thing is, if the user clicks on a certain td, that td tag's background color has to be changed to some other color and for this td the mouseout/over event should not be occurred.Means, the td's background color should not be changed on mouseover and mouseout events which has been clicked...What is wrong in my code?

Here is my code.....

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <title> New Document </title>
  <meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus">
  <meta name="Author" content="">
  <meta name="Keywords" content="">
  <meta name="Description" content="">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>

  table,table td{
   border:1px solid;
  }
  </style>
 </head>

 <body>

  <table>
   <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
   <tr><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td></tr>
   <tr><td>9</td><td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td></tr>
   <tr><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td></td></tr>
  </table>
 </body>

 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

   $('table td').mouseover(function(){
   if($(this).selected!='X')
     $(this).css({'background-color':'#ffff66'});
   });

   $('table td').mouseout(function(){
     if($(this).selected!='X')
    $(this).css({'background-color':'#fff'});
   });

  $('table td').click(function(){
    $(this).css({'background-color':'#6666ff'});
    $(this).selected='X';
   });

  });
 </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to unbind 'mouseover' and 'mouseout' after 'click' happens

Your click handler should be something like this -

```
 $('table td').click(function(){
    $(this).css({'background-color':'#6666ff'});       
    $(this).unbind('mouseout');
    $(this).unbind('mouseover');
   });
```

Or better like this -

```
$('table td').click(function(){
    var td = $(this);
    td.css({'background-color':'#6666ff'});       
    td.unbind('mouseout');
    td.unbind('mouseover');
   });
```

More about unbind [here](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

That said your code would still work if you set and access your 'selected' with index zero like this -

```
$(this)[0].selected='X'
```

`$(this)` returns a new array object each time.

Comment: Thanks, Doesn't it work with checking the variable(in my case selected) ,Is it not a proper way??